# How to ORDER BY with different columns as one column?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got the following code below:

```
$db = $this->database[GDB];
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 100 strUserId, TotalTime, Nation, LoginDT FROM USERDATA WHERE Authority IN(1, 2) ORDER BY TotalTime DESC');
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
$db->getError();
return;
}
```

**What I want to do is the following:**

`ORDER BY` like that:

```
TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT)
```

How I can do that in the query above?

I use MSSQL Server 2005

Comment: `ORDER BY TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT)`

Comment: doesnt work, there is an error and nothing appears

Comment: I mean it doesn't work and there is an error. Nothing appears just doesn't count it. Possible that I am using MSSQL Server 2005 but shouldn't since all time() and etc are supported. Is there any other way?

Comment: what `time() + 7200` constant makes for ordering? try `TotalTime - LoginDT`

Comment: @MokIk what do you mean by `time()` i think `time()` is not a built in function in sql server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
SELECT TOP 100 strUserId, TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT) as
newTotalTime, Nation, LoginDT FROM USERDATA WHERE Authority IN(1, 2)
ORDER BY newTotalTime DESC
```

Comment: i didnt because i use these values from the columns below on my script and i need them separately. is any way to group them and still use them separately?

Comment: TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT) as newTotalTime will be return as a separate column in the sql results. Basically the sql will return strUserId, newTotalTime, Nation, LoginDT with newTotaltime sorted in desc

Comment: What i meant is that I need TotalTime as standalone on top of that newTotalTime. How I can achieve that ?

Comment: You can add it in your query as 'SELECT TOP 100 strUserId, (TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT)) as newTotalTime, Nation, LoginDT, TotalTime FROM USERDATA WHERE Authority IN(1, 2) ORDER BY newTotalTime DESC'

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to this

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 100 strUserId, TotalTime, Nation, LoginDT FROM USERDATA WHERE Authority IN(1, 2) ORDER BY (TotalTime + ('.time().' + 7200 - LoginDT)) DESC');
```

Please note that the query is concatenated with [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) since it's a PHP function, not a SQL Server function.

This is the generated query

```
SELECT TOP 100 strUserId, TotalTime, Nation, LoginDT FROM USERDATA WHERE Authority IN(1, 2) ORDER BY (TotalTime + (1416132847 + 7200 - LoginDT)) DESC
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/vSR2FJ8C